# Cassandra decommission loss of data

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cluster-computing, data-loss

We are running a Cassandra cluster with node servers. Initially, the cluster only had one node, and we decided that since that node was running out of space, we could add another node to the cluster.

Info on the cluster:

Keyspace with replication factor **1** using the SimpleStrategy class on a single datacenter

`Node 1 - 256 tokens, almost no space available (1TB occupied by Cassandra data)
Node 2 - connected with 256 tokens, had 13TB available`

First we added node 2 to the cluster and then realized that to stream the data to node 2, we'd have to decommission node 1.
So we decided to decommission, empty and reconfigure node 1 (we wanted node 1 to hold only 32 tokens) and re-add node 1 to the cluster datacenter.

When launching the decommission process, it created a stream of 29 files making a total of almost 600GB. That stream copied successfully (we checked the logs and used *nodetool netstats*) and we were expecting that a second stream would follow as we had 1TB on node 1. But nothing else happened, the node reported as decommissioned and node 2 reported data stream complete.

The log from node 2 related to the copy stream:

`INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.131.155.200:48267] 2018-10-08 16:05:55,636 StreamResultFuture.java:116 - [Stream #a248d100-cb0b-11e8-a427-37a119a8af0a ID#0] Creating new streaming plan for Unbootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.131.155.200:48267] 2018-10-08 16:05:55,648 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #a248d100-cb0b-11e8-a427-37a119a8af0a, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Unbootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.131.155.200:57298] 2018-10-08 16:05:55,648 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #a248d100-cb0b-11e8-a427-37a119a8af0a, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Unbootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.131.155.200:57298] 2018-10-08 16:05:55,663 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #a248d100-cb0b-11e8-a427-37a119a8af0a ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 29 files(584.444GiB), sending 0 files(0.000KiB)
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2018-10-09 16:55:33,646 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #a248d100-cb0b-11e8-a427-37a119a8af0a] Session with /10.131.155.200 is complete
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2018-10-09 16:55:33,709 StreamResultFuture.java:219 - [Stream #a248d100-cb0b-11e8-a427-37a119a8af0a] All sessions completed`

After clearing the cassandra data folder (we should've backed it up, we know), we started cassandra again in node 1 and it successfully joined the cluster.

The cluster is functional with:

`Node 1 - 32 tokens
Node 2 - 256 tokens`

**But**, we seem to have a lost a lot of data. We were doing this as instructed in the Cassandra documentation.

We tried doing *nodetool repair* on both nodes, but to no avail (both reported no data to be recovered).

What did we miss here? Is there a way to recover this lost data?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure that node1 came up with only 32 tokens and not the original 256? It can be a little tricky to re-add a previously decommissioned node. Is the total data size on the cluster the 1Tb? Was node1 totally full before moving? Data can get corrupted if writing until full which may of misrepresented total disk usage (extra half written sstable)

Comment: As a note with default configuration you have no availability or data durability. You will need 3 replicas and be using quorum reads and writes to have full data availability with a node down. There are many data loss and no availability scenarios in your setup. If your running single RF be sure to configure it to use batch commitlog sync at least.

Comment: We're sure that the node came up with only 32 tokens. nodetool status shows this and shows ownership at around 15% for node 1 and 85% for node 2.
The total data size in the cluster currently is the copied 600GB, whilst before the decommission it was 1TB.
Node 1 had a disk space full problem a week ago, we purged some of our own data to aliviate the situation, and decided proceed with the streaming of the data to node 2 (through the decommission of node 1).

Comment: Do you think that disk space usage getting to 100% makes cassandra corrupt existing data? I would've thought it would mean cassandra simply could not store anymore data, but never to mess with the existing data.

Thank you in advance for all your help

Comment: it could of created a new sstable half way before dying, meaning that sstable is not valid making it look like you have more data than you actually do disk usage wise.

Comment: You are saying that we could have only 600GB instead of the 1TB before the decommission?
But we actually lost data. We have an application that consults data records in Cassandra, and some of the records have disappeared.

Comment: Yes i was saying that was a possibility. but if you verified data loss then thats not case.